# Does data in the firebase realtime database get accessed by any device running my app?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using firebase realtime database for my android app, so will the data in the database get accessed by any device running my application or is it unique to a single application because I haven't enabled any kind of entry authentication for users, anyone using the app can directly save their notes onto it without any sign in/sign up.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use auth for this. But you can provide your user unique ids. Because in your database you have to keep your user's data with unique ids, otherwise you database will be complex.

At the end, yes you all users can reach(as long as you provide them permissions) you database.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your Firebase Database rules:

### Examples

#### 1. No Rules

Anyone with access to your app can read or write to the database

```
 {
 “rules”: {
 “.read”: true,
 “.write”: true
 }
}
```

#### 2. Only authenticated users can read or write in database

```
{
 “rules”: {
 “.read”: true,
 “.write”: true
 }
}
```

#### 3. Nobody can read and write to the database

```
{
 “rules”: {
 “.read”: false,
 “.write”: false
 }
}
```

These are but a few rules you can have for your database, for more info and examples check out this [Documentation](https://medium.com/@juliomacr/10-firebase-realtime-database-rule-templates-d4894a118a98)

Answer (score 0):

Access to a realtime database's content is controlled by the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules). Basically they are not based on *how* (from an web application, or from a native application) but *who* accesses the data. It means that every user must be authenticated, possibly as an [anonymous user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth).

Obviously nothing prevents you to set permissive rules but it would be dangerous. Fortunately Firebase tries to warn you if your rules are insecure.

[Basic Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics) discusses common strategies : User content, Role based, Custom claims, ...